# how to re-cluster new instance in centroid base clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, rapidminer

I have applied clustering algos like k-mean, k-medoid and DBSCAN on my patients dataset. For each algo  RapidMiner generated Clustered model(centroid table and graphs etc) and clustered set(shows which examples are part of which cluster). Now I want some way that when a new patient come i want to assign him a cluster based on previous trained model. I am confused of the way to do this.. is it something like that, I may be wrong

for each attribute value of new patient - that attribute value from centroid table
summing all the differences of attributes of patient and taking avg.

then assign him cluster whose avg is minimum with respect to that patient.

if this the right way then how i will re-cluster i.e when a new patient comes our algo is assigning him cluster, that's mean. centroid moves and then I have to re-cluster with each record insertion. how to handle this in my scenario?

Comment: This question belongs on stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Look at **online clustering algorithms**, if you want to apply them to streams.

There exist things such as **online k-means variants**.

Usually, you do indeed want to avoid re-clustering all existing examples, because that won't work with infinite data streams and finite memory.

Usually it is a good idea to **not** try to get the exact same result as if you had run the classic clustering algorithm, but learn to live with some error. After all, all these algorithms are already just heuristics anyway. As long as your approximation is good, there is nothing wrong with approximating an heuristic.